# Array/Vec pointer foreach c (ffi c in rust) to swift

Tags: c, swift, foreach, rust, ffi

How can I read the string value in swift of my array with a foreach ?

My code in rust is :

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct DynArray {
    array: *mut CharTest,
    length: size_t,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct CharTest {
    char_test: *const c_char,
}

#[no_mangle] // *const c_char
pub extern "C" fn simple_svg(max_size: c_double) -> DynArray {
    let data = DataChartNatalC {
        year: 2000,
        month: 01,
        day: 01,
        hourf32: 0.0,
        hour: 0,
        min: 0,
        sec: 0.0,
        lat: 0.0,
        lng: 0.0,
    };
    let mut v: Vec<CharTest> = Vec::new();
    v.push(CharTest {
        char_test: CString::new(astrology_draw_svg::chart(
            max_size as f32,
            data,
        ))
        .unwrap()
        .into_raw(),
    });
    v.push(CharTest {
        char_test: CString::new("test").unwrap().into_raw(),
    });

    let result = DynArray {
        array: v.as_mut_ptr(),
        length: v.len() as _,
    };
    std::mem::forget(v);
    result
}
```

The header .h is :

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  const char *char_test;
} CharTest;

typedef struct {
  CharTest *array;
  size_t length;
} DynArray;


DynArray simple_svg(double max_size);
```

And in swift I have no idea what is the best foreach method to archive it

I tried

```
            let test = simple_svg(maxSize)
            for t in test.array {
                print("Test: {}", String.init(t.char_test))
s            }
```

But i have this error :

> Type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?' does not conform to protocol
>   'Sequence'

Comment: and what have you tried in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use for-in on a pointer. As the error message is clearly saying you need some type conforming to `Sequence`.

One example of `Sequence` which works with pointers is `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`.
You can convert the result type `DynArray` to `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CharTest>`.

```
extension DynArray {
    var asBufferPointer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CharTest> {
        return UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: array, count: length)
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let test = simple_svg(maxSize)
for t in test.asBufferPointer {
    print("Test: \(String(cString: t.char_test))")
}
```

Or you can access elements by using index, without such conversion:

```
for index in 0..<test.length {
    let t = test.array[index]
    print("Test: \(String(cString: t.char_test))")
}
```